# How to extract a part of data, that we get from website using url.open()

Tags: python, web, text-parsing

I wrote a Program that connects to this website

http://mbox.dr-chuck.net/sakai.devel/1/2

I need to parse it and get email in that website

```
url = http://mbox.dr-chuck.net/sakai.devel/1/2
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
for line in data:
    templine = line.strip()
    print templine
```

but it prints individual letters instead of words
like when i try to print a particular line from it

```
F
r
o
m

n
e
w
s
```

how to fix this please help me
what to do,I need my program to print as lines

- sorry about my language, this is my first question to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = 'http://mbox.dr-chuck.net/sakai.devel/1/2'
data = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines()
for line in data:
    if line.startswith('From'):
        print (line)
```

out:

```
From news@gmane.org Tue Mar 04 03:33:20 2003

From: "Glenn R. Golden" <ggolden@umich.edu>
```

use `readlines()` to get each line in the file

use `startswith()` to get line which starts with `From`

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `python3`, you can do something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = urlopen("http://mbox.dr-chuck.net/sakai.devel/1/2").read().decode("utf8").split("\n")

for k in data:
    print(k)
```

Update:

If you want to print only the second line from the given url, you can do something like this:

```
print(data[1])
>>> 'From: "Glenn R. Golden" <ggolden@umich.edu>'
```

otherwise, if you want to print all the lines which starts with `From` or `From:`, you can do something like this:

```
for k in data:
    if k.split(" ")[0] == "From" or k.split(" ")[0] == "From:":
        print(k)
```

Output:

```
From news@gmane.org Tue Mar 04 03:33:20 200
From: "Glenn R. Golden" <ggolden@umich.edu>
```

Comment: But I don't need to print all data I need to print a particular line

Comment: Please clarify which line you want to print or extract. And please update your question too.

Comment: Line starts with 'From: ' ( 2nd line )

Comment: I've updated my answer. Accept it if it fills your needs. Thanks.

Comment: What if I don't know that its 2nd line and I need to print a line in a 1000 lines document that starts with a particular string

Comment: it works pretty fine incase of file if we write like this

Comment: I am using python 2

Comment: You should mention this in your question. Please edit edit.

Comment: Sorry this is my first question but solved it by using readlines() instead of read()